# Can I connect to an on premise Microsoft SQL Server and an Azure file share in the same SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

The issue that I am having is that I am not able to connect to an Azure file share and an on premise SQL Server in the same SSIS package. The set up that is being used is that the connection to the on-premise server needs to use Windows authentication, SQL Server authentication is not an option due to policy.

The SSIS package is being executed using an execute SSIS package activity inside of an Azure Data Factory Pipeline. In the execute SSIS package activity there is an option to use Windows authentication. I am able to use Windows authentication with the correct domain, username, and password to access the SQL Server on premise.

From what I have read, when you are connecting to an Azure file share you have to use Azure as the domain, the file share name as the username and the access key as the password. From this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/ssis-azure-connect-with-windows-auth

When I try to connect to the on premise server while using those credentials, I am unable to connect. I have tried overriding the connection string with new credentials, but that also fails. I have not been able to find a way to connect using anything but `Integrated Security=SSPI` in the connection string, and that does not work with the file share credentials in the Windows authentication override in the pipeline.

Comment: Could you please clarify which resources you are able to connect to?  It sounds like you were able to connect to the on prem SQL, but that broke when you tried to configure credentials to the azure file share?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz That is correct.  To clarify, I am able to connect to either resource independently, but not both resources in the same SSIS package.  My understanding from the Azure documentation is that each activity in the pipeline can only execute using a single set of credentials.  Since the credentials needed to connect to the two resources are different, it is not possible to connect to both in the same execute SSIS activity.  It looks like breaking the SSIS package so that only one set of credentials is needed is a viable option, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

After working with Microsoft resources, it was determined that this was not possible to connect in the same pipeline activity to both an Azure file share and a SQL server that required Windows authentication.  Link to documentation in original post.